# Need to change the email recipient dynamically using log4j2 SMTP

Tags: java, email, log4j2

I'm trying to send emails via log4j2. I have a requirement to change the recipient of the email at runtime.

I can set this via code using:

```
ThreadContext.put(USER_EMAILS, "jhutc@company.com");
```

However, if I attempt to set this up using:

```
<SMTP name="Mail" subject="MoLi Tests"
    to="%X{userEmails}" from="jhutc@company.com"
    smtpHost="mail.company.com" smtpPort="25" bufferSize="1">
    <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT"
    onMismatch="DENY" />
    <PatternLayout pattern="%m %X{userEmails}"/>
</SMTP>
```

I get the following exception:

> 2016-11-15 12:07:31,904 main ERROR Error occurred while sending e-mail notification. com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 451 4.3.2 Please try again later

Note using `to="jhutc@company.com"` works fine, and proves that the userEmails variable has been successfully placed into the ThreadContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code scope in your code block

```
public static void main(String ara[])
{

Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(xxx.class);

try
{
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    p.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    ThreadContext.put("userEmails","to@gmail.com");

    LOGGER.log(LOG_LEVEL, "TEST"); // your choice level
    int a = 4 / 0;

} catch (Throwable e)
{

        LOGGER.log(LOG_LEVEL, "TEST");
    }
```